# Can I use StandardScaler() on whole data set, or should I calculate on train and test sets separately?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, scaling

I'm developing a SVR for ~100 continuous features and a continuous label.

For scaling the data, I wrote:

```
#Read in
df = pd.read_csv(data_path,sep='\t')
features = df.iloc[:,1:-1] #100 features
target = df.iloc[:,-1] #The label
names = df.iloc[:,0] #Column names


#Scale features
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(features)


# rename columns (since now its an np array)
features.columns = df_columns
```

So now I have a scaled data frame, and my next step was to split into train and test, and then develop a model (SVR):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_df, target, test_size=0.2)
model = SVR()
```

...and then I fit the model to the data.

But I noticed other people don't fit the StandardScaler() to the whole data frame, but they split the dataframe into train and test first, and then apply StandardScaler() to each separately.

Is there a difference between whether you apply the StandardScaler to the whole data frame, or train and test separately?

Comment: That said, there is a simple rule of thumb regarding the test set: during the modeling phase, *pretend that it does not even exist*. And if it does not exist, you cannot include it in your scaling, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer says that you should separate the training and testing set when scaling, otherwise the testing one might bias the transformation of the training one. This is half correct and half wrong.

If you do the transformation separately, then it might well be that the training set will get scaled to wrong proportions (e.g. if it comes from a narrow continuous time range, thus taking on a subset of the values range). You will end up having wrong values for the variables of the test set.

In general, what you must do is scale on the training set *and transfer the scale over to the testing set*. This is done by using the methods `fit` and `transform` separately, as seen in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply StandardScaler to the training set to prevent the distribution of the test set leaking into the model. If you fit the scaler on the full dataset before splitting, the test set information is used to transform the training set and use it to train the model.